# Reading off Amplitude from scipy spectrogram

Tags: python, scipy, fft, dft, spectrogram

It seems to me that the amplitude calculated in scipy.signal.spectrogram is not correct (in my case about 20% off). Is it possible to improve on this? Consider this example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import pi as π

f_s = 200              # Sampling rate = number of measurements per second in [Hz]
t   = np.arange(-10,10, 1 / f_s)
N = len(t)
T1  = np.tanh(t)/2  + 1.0 # Period in [s]
T2  = 0.125               # Period in [s]
f1  = 1 / T1            # Frequency in [Hz]
f2  = 1 / T2            # Frequency in [Hz] 

# Signal
x = 13*np.sin(2 * π * f1 * t) + 42*np.sin(2 * π * f2 * t)

# Spectrogram with good time window
Δt = 4 # window length in [s]
Nw = np.int(2**np.round(np.log2(Δt * f_s)))
print(f"Effective window length is {Nw/f_s:.1f}s")
f, t_, Sxx = signal.spectrogram(x, f_s, window='hanning', nperseg=Nw, noverlap = Nw - 100, detrend=False, scaling='spectrum')
Δf  =  f[1] - f[0]
Δt_ = t_[1] - t_[0]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (15,5))
im = ax.pcolormesh(t_ + t[0] - Δt_, f - Δf/2, np.sqrt(Sxx), cmap = "inferno_r")
plt.colorbar(im)
ax.grid(True)
ax.set_ylabel("Frequency in [Hz]")
ax.set_xlabel("t")
ax.set_ylim(0,10)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Clearly, the lines do not show their amplitudes defined before (which would be 13 and 42).

Comment: It looks like they do. From your color bar on the side, 13 is roughly orange which is the bottom line, and 42 is dark purple which is what it looks to be on the spectrogram. What do you expect to see?

Comment: `np.sqrt(Sxx)` would give you values approximately proportional to the **RMS** amplitude of your sinusoidal inputs. In your case that would be 13*0.7071~9 and 42*0.7071~30. You may find these values better correspond to your plot.